# Knockout js registerEvent handler

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm having a great time playing around with knockout js and have just started to get to grips with adding custom bindingHandlers.

I'm struggling a bit with the update function of a 3rd party jqWidget gauge - I can only get it to animate the first time I update the variable. On each update after that it just sets the value directly.

I don't fully understand ko.utils.registerEventHandler() and what it does although I've seen it in a bunch of other examples. Is this what is causing the animation to break? How do I know which events to register from the 3rd party widget?

For some reason this works fine if I add a jquery ui slider that is also bound to the observable.

You can test this here: set the value a few times to see that it animates the first time and not after that.

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/4531/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update the input field, your observable will end up being a string.  It looks like the gauge does not like to be updated with a string value, at least after the first time.

So, if you ensure that you are updating it with a number (`parseInt`, `parseFloat`, or just `+` depending on the situation), then it appears to update fine.

Something like:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var gaugeval = parseInt(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()), 10);   
    $(element).jqxGauge('value', gaugeval || 0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/4532/

You would generally only register event handlers in a scenario like this to react to changes made by a user where you would want to update your view model data.  For example, if there was a way for a user to click on the gauge to change the value, then you would want to handle that event and update your view model value accordingly.

Comment: ah thanks - I didn't think knockout was to blame...ok so that explains why I needed to add the registerEvent handlers to the slider so that it has the ability to update the viewmodel. Glad it was as simple as parsing an int!

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering the

> I don't fully understand ko.utils.registerEventHandler() and what it does

part of your question.

`registerEventHandler` will register your event handler function in a cross-browser compatible way. If you are using jQuery, Knockout will use jQuery's `bind` function to register the event handler. Otherwise, will use the browser Web API with a consistent behavior across browsers.

You can check it out on [the source code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js).